# Is there a way to find out whether a website is opened through a redirect from another one in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect

If I have a domain which is:

```
(1) http://www.myownsite.com
```

And I have another domain that has a link to it:

```
(2) http://www.pointingtomyownsite.com
```

Is there a way to find out whether (1) is opened through a redirect from (2) in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "redirect".  If you mean a CNAME DNS entry (where one hostname appears in the browser even though the page is served from another host, and which many people incorrectly call a DNS redirect), then Senad's answer is correct, Request.Url.Host will work. (This is *not* a redirect BTW).

A *real* redirect will change the hostname shown in the browser window, and you can get the URL of the previous page using [HttpRequest.UrlReferrer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer(v=vs.110).aspx).  This works for both redirects and links. Although the Referer HTTP header this property exposes is not technically required and may be NULL, in practice it will be sent by all the browsers you should care about except for possibly if the URL was entered directly on a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

```
var hostname = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host
```